# Removing duplicate highway shield symbol labels from ArcMap document

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, duplication

I have highway shield symbols in my map document that are showing duplicate labels in the current map view. When I go to the Properties of the roads layer, then Labels, then Placement Properties and select Remove Duplicate Labels and click OK, the duplicate labels do not disappear.

Also to note, I am using the Standard Labeling Engine and not the Maplex Labeling Engine and have to use the Standard Labeling Engine due to Maplex not being supported by our vendor application where the mxd is loaded.

Comment: By any chance are your road segments broken into many small segments and Arc is trying to label each segment.  I run into this problem a bit, and end up dissolving the field on the name, then using the newly dissolved layer to label the original layer.

Comment: I am actually using a shapefile that is a Dissolved version of my original roads shapefile. The fields we're required to Dissolve on are Street Name, Segment Type (feature type), and One Way (direction of travel) field. Also, yes, the road segments are already broken into several smaller segments to create intersection junctions for SQL's Intersection table. Would you be able to suggest an additional method / tool to resolve duplicate shield symbol labels that appear within the current map view - using the Standard Labeling Engine? Possibly using Conflict Detection options or others?

Comment: Ok,  just to clarify because I could be totally misunderstanding the question.  You have a new roads layer that is still broken into many segments and each of those segments is being labeled?  I think you should again dissolve the road segments into 1 large segment (that way it only gets 1 label)  Then in the new layer make the newly dissolved line features "no color/no fill" so they cant be seen,  then turn the Labeling on that layer, so then you will only get 1 label for the entire feature.

Comment: Ok - are you suggesting to use the Dissolve Tool on my (already once) dissolved roads shapefile to Dissolve it one more time to Unsplit Lines more, so that they become more close to 1 whole segment? My current dissolved roads shapefile has unsplit the lines to a certain degree, but not completely or as unsplit as they could be. Is there a way or method to specify in the Dissolve Tool how to more completely unsplit line segments, so that I am left with only 1 segment showing in the mxd?

Comment: If you dissolve the segement on only 1 attribute,  I would think for you it would be the field that holds the roads name,  then you should have only 1 segment for each road.   make the linework invisible and turn the labels on and i think it should do what you want.